# Why is my y axis stacking values from the y values I'm trying to plot for multiple lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I am trying to graph data across time for multiple subjects. All subjects have the same x-value timepoints and the y-values are all floats.

When I go to plot a subject's data, the y-axis is using the y-values as y-ticks and isn't plotting how it should. When I add another subject's data to the plot, it stacks the y-values on top of the previous subject's, essentially continuing the issue. I have numerous other plots and subplots where this has not been happening. I don't know why this is occurring for three particular variables in my dataset.

please help!

I have tried both the plt.plot() method and fig, ax=plt.subplots(), which shared the same results.

```
plt.plot(S11.Visit, S16.BSS, label="S16")
plt.plot(S11.Visit, S19.BSS, label="S19")
plt.plot(S11.Visit, S11.BSS, label="S11")

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: 3 subjects' data with y-axis not conforming for all three]

Here is the code for the subplots using group averages. The same thing occurs where each y-value is used as a y-tick and they're stacked on top of each other rather than conforming to the same y-axis

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(3,1, sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Exp_Avg.BSS, marker='o', color='firebrick', label='Exp Avg')
ax[0].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Con_Avg.BSS, marker='o', color='black', label='Con Avg')
ax[0].set_ylabel("BSS")


ax[1].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Exp_Avg.POMS, marker='o', color='firebrick', label='Exp Avg')
ax[1].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Con_Avg.POMS, marker='o', color='black', label='Con Avg')
ax[1].set_ylabel("POMS")


ax[2].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Exp_Avg.WURSS, marker='o', color='firebrick', label='Exp Avg')
ax[2].plot(Exp_Avg.Visit, Con_Avg.WURSS, marker='o', color='black', label='Con Avg')
ax[2].set_ylabel("WURSS")
ax[2].set_xlabel("Visit")
ax[0].legend()

ax[0].set_title("Control vs. Experimental subjective scores")

fig.set_size_inches(10,8)

plt.show()
```

[image: 3 subplots with group averages of 3 different variables... the y-values are stacking and the y-axis is not conforming to both groups' data]

What I want to happen is for each variable to have a shared y-axis and tick value for all groups/individuals plotted on that graph. I took a screenshot of what it should look like in excel.

[image: What the three graphs should look like- Excel version]

Comment: Are the y-axis values in string type?　`Exp_Avg.BSS = Exp_Avg.BSS.astype(float)`

Comment: All three variables are listed as objects